# Unusual hybrid nested raid array configuration (raid 1 AND 5)?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, software-raid, array

I was wondering about your thoughts on an off-the-wall raid configuration with 4 disks.  Ignoring performance hits (which I expect to be bad), could one configure a raid 1 array with one leg begin a normal disk and the other leg being a three disk raid 5 array?  Would I gain the error correction of raid 5 on the one leg while getting a slight performance and rebuild improvement from the redundant data on the normal single disk of the other leg?

Is there any hardware or OS / utility that would allow such a configuration (even if just as a proof of concept)?  Would this improve on even raid 6 rebuild fault tolerance?

Answer (score -1):

This is absolutely technically possible.  For example, can you take three 1TB hard drives and use hardware RAID5 to make a 2TB volume and use the OS to create a software RAID1 with a 2TB hard disk and the RAID1 volume.  Since the RAID5 is at the hardware level, the fact it is 3 drives is abstracted from the OS.

However, you are mistaken in the fact you would gain any error correction.  RAID does not offer any error correction.  RAID5 offers *redundancy* and thats all.  In this configuration, you could lose all 3 disks in the RAID5 and still have not lost data.  Also, you could lose the single hard disk and 1 one of the RAID5 disks and still have not lost any data.

This configuration really doesnt gain you much, to much depends on which disks fail.

Comment: Thx for your reply. To clarify what I meant... I was hoping that the raid5 leg would provide some error protection / correction from bit rot (if I scrub it periodically).  Also, the single disk on the other raid1 leg would possibly provide some protection from an unrecoverable error on the raid5 array while rebuilding a failed array, maybe? [but only if the rebuild routine skips the file(s) by the bad block(s)]?